# Perforce: Is it possible to execute an integrate command on multiple files (not folders)?

Tags: file, batch-file, perforce, edit, integrate

I'm trying to execute an "Integrate" perforce command (see: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/integrate.html) on a list of files and not on a single file or a specific folder.

Is such a thing possible ?

In other words, is it possible to specify multiple files (and their respective integration paths) in one command ? This would save me the trouble of having to call this command for each file that I'd like to integrate and in the process reduces the number of round-trips on the P4 server.

If not, do you have another command to recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a branch, and then integrate through the branch. I know that sounds weird, but in Perforce all a branch is is a set of integration mappings stored in the server. You then use `-b` on `p4 integrate` to specify the branch.

Comment: So you recommand that I use this command ? : http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/branch.html . Am I not forced to specify a directory when creating a branch .. ? (Sorry, Perforce "newbie" here :))

Comment: A branch view usually maps directory trees, but it doesn't have to. Your branch spec can have file to file mappings. eg: `//depot/foo/bar.txt //depot/baz/quux.txt'. One possibly confusing thing is that when you run `p4 integrate` you tell it the names of the destination files, not the names of the source files (it gets those from the branch spec).

Answer (score 0):

In p4v you can `Ctrl+click` multiple files, then right-click and choose to `Integrate` them.  I don't think you can do anything fancy as far as integration paths; that is if you are integrating two files in the same source directory it will assume the same target directory.  Or, if you are integrating two files `dev/dir1/file1` and `dev/dir2/file2` you can choose `dev2/...` as your target directory and you will have `dev2/dir1/file1` and `dev2/dir2/file2`.

Edit to add:  If you are looking for a command line solution, you can use Laurence's and edit the branch specification to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

You can operate on a filelist using:

```
p4 -x filelist.txt
```

See

```
p4 help usage
```

> The -x flag instructs p4 to read arguments, one per line, from the
> specified file.  If you specify '-', standard input is read.

You could pass the arguments to p4 integrate directly this way or you could use the same method to create a label

```
p4 -x filelist.txt tag -l mylabel
```

And then reference the label on source side of an integration

```
p4 integrate //depot/src_stream/...@mylabel //depot/target_stream/...
```